# A custom array-type object that pulls data from different sources

Tags: ruby

I want to design a class that behaves like an array, but also allows me to separate one set of data from another set so that certain operations only act on data from the other set. What is a good way to do this?

My design is to have initial set of data stored in one array, and any new elements that are added to this object are tracked separately (called "extra" data) in a different array.

Adding and deleting items from objects of this class will operate on the new elements only, while any sort of search operations will be performed on the combination of the initial elements as well as the new elements.

An element's index in this object is the element's index in the concatenation of the two arrays, so if there are 3 elements in the initial data and 4 elements in the extra array, then the first element in the extra array will return an index of 3, while the first element of the initial array will return an index of 0.

For illustration purposes this is how it might look in code

```
class MyClass

  def initialize(base_data)
    @base_elements = base_data # this is an array
    @extra_elements = []       # this stores the "new" data
  end

  def add(elem)
    @extra_elements << elem
  end

  def delete(elem)
    @extra_elements << elem
  end

  def all_elements
    @base_elements.concat(@extra_elements)
  end

  def find(elem)
    all_elements.find( ... )
  end

  def index (elem)
    all_elements.index( ... )
  end
end
```

Ideally, this should support all of the methods defined in `Enumerator` as well, such as `each`, `inject`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty much there based on what you are asking for just a couple modifications:

```
class MyClass
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(base_data)
    @base_elements = base_data # this is an array
    @extra_elements = []       # this stores the "new" data
  end

  def add(elem)
    @extra_elements << elem
  end

  def delete(elem)
    @extra_elements.delete(elem)
  end

  def all_elements
    @base_elements.concat(@extra_elements)
  end

  def index (elem)
    all_elements.index( ... )
  end

  def each(&block)
    all_elements.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking of including the Enumerable module, however I am not sure if I could then just treat it as an enumerable without overriding all of the different methods to have them handle the two arrays.

Comment: The `Enumerable` defines its various methods in terms of your `each` method. Since Alex has defined an `each` method that uses `all_elements`, then all of the `Enumerable` methods will use `all_elements` too.